# <ol> list type not displaying when using CSS3 multi-column layout

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm using the CSS3 multi-column layout for an ordered list, but the list-numbers for the individual list-items's aren't being displayed in the second column.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7j0nh50/).

Sample code is below.

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

And CSS:

```
ol {
    -moz-column-count 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the default `padding` on the `ol` allows for the numbers to be displayed. By default, they are displayed on the outside of the element, and since the second column doesn't have an padding, they aren't displayed.

You could position them on the inside by adding `list-style-position: inside`:

```css
ol {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use [CSS3 counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) and displaying the number on the `li` element using a pseudo element:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/qcnn4f03/)

```css
ol {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: list;
}
li:before {
  counter-increment: list;
  content: counter(list) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! Looks like it's a bug in Safari and IE. I was thinking of using a counter as well, but I wasn't sure if there was something I was missing here,